# Получить sha256 для каждой строки массива. Подскажите способ быстрее

Tags: linux, sha, sha256

Требуется получить хэш sha256 от каждой строки сгенерированного большого массива.
Пока ничего лучшего не нашел, чем

```
generator | while IFS= read -r var; do echo -n "$var" | sha256sum; done
```

но это все же достаточно медленно...
смена команды на `openssl dgst -sha256 -hex` или `shasum -a 256`
принципиальной разницы не дает...
Есть способы явно более быстрые?
bash, python, perl,... если действительно быстрее -предлагайте...
Слышал что rust быстрый, но написать на нем не в состоянии, могу разве что скомпилировать -запустить готовый полный скрипт (cargo установил).

Comment: Проблема скрипта в том, что он каждый раз запускает новый процесс для каждой строки. На любом полноценном языке программирования можно сделать намного быстрее

Comment: Используйте хотя бы python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v1.0 - чтение из файла
      #Python3
    import hashlib

```
def sha256_generate(string):
    print(hashlib.sha256(string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open('file.txt')
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.replace('''
''', '');
        sha256_generate(line)
```

Файл со строками должен лежать в той же директории где и скрипт

---

v2.0 - чтение из консоли

```
import hashlib

def sha256_generate(string):
    print(64 * "-") #Эта строка отвечает за вывод отделителя, её можно удалить
    print(hashlib.sha256(string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
    print(64 * "-") #Эта строка отвечает за вывод отделителя, её можно удалить
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while(True):
        line = str(input())
        sha256_generate(line)
```

Для выхода Ctrl+C

Comment: Можешь многопоточность сделать

Comment: Многопоточность только ухудшит всё. Основное время занимает чтение из диска, а не расчет хеша.

Comment: @Allespro Работает быстро, НО выдает неправильный sha256 ! То есть он выдает как `echo foo | sha256sum`, а надо как `echo -n foo | sha256sum`... как поправить?

Comment: ИМХО. Работает он правильно, считает хеш не тот из за того, что на конце строки есть символ. посмотри картинку https://d.radikal.ru/d22/1902/ae/100dca8fb6cf.png а вот сами хеши https://c.radikal.ru/c18/1902/5b/086e2c24f002.png

Comment: I update code, chek it

Comment: @Allespro Я не знаю, из-за чего, я не настолько в этом понимаю( , но опять же у вас в скринах `echo dfssdfsdfsdfsfd | sha256sum` , а мне надо `echo -n dfssdfsdfsdfsfd | sha256sum` . Исправленный код у меня не работает.

Comment: @Bl0wfish вот код https://pastebin.com/pe2nqQPt можешь сказать что не работает, у меня вывод `echo -n dfssdfsdfsdfsfd | sha256sum` совпадает с выводом программы

Comment: @Allespro Вы, правы, ваш скрипт работает правильно. Я столкнулся на ubuntu со странной ошибкой pip hashlib описанной тут https://askubuntu.com/questions/770262/python-hashlib-fails-to-install-pip, после исправления заработало правильно. Спасибо. Если не сложно, не могли бы вы поправить код, чтобы использовать скрипт в трубе, без чтения из файла?

Comment: @Bl0wfish думаю не сложно, только я не совсем понял, что он будет делать. Смутило слово труба

Comment: @Allespro труба -pipe. чтобы брал не из файла, а из stdin и выдавал в stdout соответственно

Comment: Добавил код, посмотри

Comment: @Allespro Да, работает, спасибо. Только завершается каждый раз `Traceback (most recent call last): File "./256pipe.py", line 11, in <module> line = str(input()) EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

Comment: @Bl0wfish в чём проблема не знаю, не сталкивался, если получится, то исправлю.